# Segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes with wheel factorisation

Tags: performance, algorithm, rust, memory-optimization, sieve-of-eratosthenes

#### Problem

I have [a project](https://nest.pijul.com/nicoty/sieve:code_review) in which I implemented variants of the Sieve of Eratosthenes as well as benchmarking and profiling harnesses for these (which can be ran with `./run.sh benchmark` and `./run.sh profile`, respectively; the results can then be accessed from the "./target/criterion/" directory). I'd like some assistance in trying to figure out why the `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` variant seems to produce primes at a slower rate relative to the other "counted" sieves (`CountedSieve`, `WheelFactorisedCountedSieve` and `SegmentedCountedSieve`), even though it should theoretically be faster than all of them (since it uses all of their optimisations).

For context, [this page has some explanations about what wheel factorisation is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), and [this page has some explanations about what a segmented sieve is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve).

#### Benchmarking Results

Here are some graphs showing the average time per iteration for each of `CountedSieve`, `WheelFactorisedCountedSieve`, `SegmentedCountedSieve` and `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` (all having calculated 1,000,000 primes, with 3 seed primes used by the wheel factorised variants and sample size of 100 each), respectively:

[image: Counted, Amount: 1000000, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Segmented Counted, Amount: 1000000, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Sample Size: 100]

And this was the terminal's output:

```
$ ./run.sh benchmark
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.22s
     Running `target/release/examples/criterion --bench`
WARNING: HTML report generation will become a non-default optional feature in Criterion.rs 0.4.0.
This feature is being moved to cargo-criterion (https://github.com/bheisler/cargo-criterion) and will be optional in a future version of Criterion.rs. To silence this warning, either switch to cargo-criterion or enable the 'html_reports' feature in your Cargo.toml.

Gnuplot not found, using plotters backend
Benchmarking Sieves/Counted/Amount = 1000000: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 2050.5s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Counted/Amount = 1000000
                        time:   [393.87 ms 394.04 ms 394.28 ms]
Found 16 outliers among 100 measurements (16.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low severe
  1 (1.00%) low mild
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  11 (11.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Segmented Counted/Amount = 1000000: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 1398.4s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Segmented Counted/Amount = 1000000
                        time:   [276.96 ms 277.28 ms 277.70 ms]
Found 14 outliers among 100 measurements (14.00%)
  6 (6.00%) low mild
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  7 (7.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Seeds = 3: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 946.7s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Seeds = 3
                        time:   [187.42 ms 187.44 ms 187.47 ms]
Found 12 outliers among 100 measurements (12.00%)
  3 (3.00%) low severe
  3 (3.00%) low mild
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  2 (2.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Seeds = 3: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 5399.2s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Seeds = 3
                        time:   [1.0644 s 1.0656 s 1.0669 s]
Found 1 outliers among 100 measurements (1.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild
```

Evidently, the segmented, wheel factorised variant took the longest time per run.

#### Profiling Results

Here's a flame graph generated from profiling `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` for 1 minute, having it attempt to calculate 1,000,000 primes with 3 seed primes for wheel factorisation:

[image: Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Duration: 60 seconds]

Evidently, most of the time spent by `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` is on calls to `WheelFactorisedSegment::new`, but I can't tell if that's primarily because of the number of segments or of the performance of `WheelFactorisedSegment::new`.

I've been reviewing the code for a couple of days but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the segmented, wheel factorised variant for it to run so much slower, or how I might improve its performance to at least be on par with the other variants. Some help diagnosing this would be greatly appreciated.

#### Code

To review the project, it's probably easiest just to clone from the repository, and perhaps run `cargo doc --no-deps` to generate and peruse the documentation (which can then be accessed from "./target/doc/sieve/index.html") for the most important parts. That said, I've included the most important parts of the code here (taken from "src/lib.rs") for convenience:

```rust
use std::{
    cell::RefCell,
    cmp::{max, min},
    mem::swap,
    rc::Rc,
};

const CACHE_BYTES: usize = 8_000;

fn prime_count_overestimate(a: usize) -> usize {
    let ln_a = (a as f64).ln();
    ((a as f64 / ln_a) * (1.0 + 1.2762 / ln_a)).ceil() as usize
}

fn prime_count_underestimate(a: usize) -> usize {
    let f_a = a as f64;
    (f_a / f_a.ln()).floor() as usize
}

fn inverse_prime_count(a: usize) -> usize {
    let f_a = a as f64;
    let ln_a = f_a.ln();
    (f_a * (ln_a + ln_a.ln() - 1.0 + 1.8 * ln_a.ln() / ln_a)).ceil() as usize + 16
}

pub struct SizedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
}

impl SizedSieve {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            list: vec![true; size],
            index: 2,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SizedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.list
                    .iter_mut()
                    .skip(self.index.pow(2))
                    .step_by(self.index)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                    });
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        if !self.list.is_empty() {
            let (underestimate, overestimate) = (
                prime_count_underestimate(self.list.len() - 1),
                prime_count_overestimate(self.list.len() - 1),
            );
            match (underestimate < self.count, overestimate < self.count) {
                (false, false) => (underestimate - self.count, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
                (false, true) => (underestimate - self.count, None),
                (true, false) => (0, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
                _ => (0, None),
            }
        } else {
            (0, None)
        }
    }
}

pub struct CountedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl CountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize) -> Self {
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        Self {
            list: vec![true; size],
            index: 2,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        while self.index <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.list
                    .iter_mut()
                    .skip(self.index.pow(2))
                    .step_by(self.index)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                    });
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for CountedSieve {}

fn gcd(mut u: usize, mut v: usize) -> usize {
    if u == 0 {
        return v;
    } else if v == 0 {
        return u;
    }

    let k = {
        let i = u.trailing_zeros();
        let j = v.trailing_zeros();
        u >>= i;
        v >>= j;
        min(i, j)
    };

    loop {
        debug_assert!(u % 2 == 1, "u = {} is even", u);
        debug_assert!(v % 2 == 1, "v = {} is even", v);

        if u > v {
            swap(&mut u, &mut v);
        }
        v -= u;

        if v == 0 {
            return u << k;
        }

        v >>= v.trailing_zeros();
    }
}

struct Totatives {
    number: usize,
    current: usize,
}

impl Totatives {
    fn new(number: usize) -> Self {
        Self { number, current: 1 }
    }

    fn is_coprime(&self, number: usize) -> bool {
        gcd(self.number, number).eq(&1)
    }
}

impl Iterator for Totatives {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.current < self.number {
            if self.is_coprime(self.current) {
                let current = self.current;
                self.current += 1;
                return Some(current);
            }
            self.current += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (0, Some(self.number - self.current))
    }
}

struct Wheel {
    seeds: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    modulus: usize,
    totatives: Vec<usize>,
    inverse_totatives: Vec<Option<usize>>,
}

impl Wheel {
    fn new(amount: usize) -> Self {
        let seeds: Vec<usize> = CountedSieve::new(amount).collect();
        let modulus = seeds.iter().product();
        let totatives: Vec<usize> = Totatives::new(modulus).collect();
        let inverse_totatives = {
            let mut out: Vec<Option<usize>> = vec![None; *totatives.last().unwrap() + 1];
            totatives.iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index, &number)| {
                out[number] = Some(index);
            });
            out
        };
        Self {
            seeds: Rc::new(seeds),
            modulus,
            inverse_totatives,
            totatives,
        }
    }

    fn inverse_totative(&self, index: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        *self.inverse_totatives.get(index)?
    }

    fn to_number(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
        self.modulus * (index / self.totatives.len()) + self.totatives[index % self.totatives.len()]
    }

    fn to_index(&self, number: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        Some(
            self.totatives.len() * (number / self.modulus)
                + self.inverse_totative(number % self.modulus)?,
        )
    }
}

pub struct WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    wheel: Wheel,
    seed_index: usize,
    end_number: usize,
}

impl WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    pub fn new(size: usize, seed_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Wheel::new(seed_amount);
        Self {
            list: vec![
                true;
                (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).ceil()
                    as usize + seed_amount
                    + 1
            ],
            index: 1,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            seed_index: 0,
            end_number: size,
            wheel,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.seed_index < self.wheel.seeds.len() {
            let prime = self.wheel.seeds[self.seed_index];
            if prime < self.end_number {
                self.count += 1;
                self.seed_index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            return None;
        }
        while self.wheel.to_number(self.index) <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                if prime < self.end_number {
                    self.count += 1;
                    for factor_index in self.index..self.list.len() {
                        if let Some(multiple_index) = self
                            .wheel
                            .to_index(prime * self.wheel.to_number(factor_index))
                        {
                            if multiple_index < self.list.len() {
                                self.list[multiple_index] = false;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.index += 1;
                    return Some(prime);
                }
                return None;
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                if prime < self.end_number {
                    self.count += 1;
                    self.index += 1;
                    return Some(prime);
                }
                return None;
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let (underestimate, overestimate) = (
            prime_count_underestimate(self.end_number),
            prime_count_overestimate(self.end_number),
        );
        match (underestimate < self.count, overestimate < self.count) {
            (false, false) => (underestimate - self.count, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
            (false, true) => (underestimate - self.count, None),
            (true, false) => (0, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
            _ => (0, None),
        }
    }
}

pub struct WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    wheel: Wheel,
    seed_index: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize, seed_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Wheel::new(seed_amount);
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        Self {
            list: vec![
                true;
                (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).floor()
                    as usize + seed_amount
                    + 1
            ],
            index: 1,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            wheel,
            seed_index: 0,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if self.seed_index < self.wheel.seeds.len() {
            let prime = self.wheel.seeds[self.seed_index];
            self.count += 1;
            self.seed_index += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        while self.wheel.to_number(self.index) <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                self.count += 1;
                for factor_index in self.index..self.list.len() {
                    if let Some(multiple_index) = self
                        .wheel
                        .to_index(prime * self.wheel.to_number(factor_index))
                    {
                        if multiple_index < self.list.len() {
                            self.list[multiple_index] = false;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {}

fn smallest_multiple_at_least(factor: usize, minimum: usize) -> usize {
    let remainder = (minimum + factor) % factor;
    if remainder != 0 {
        minimum + factor - remainder
    } else {
        minimum
    }
}

struct Segment {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    start: usize,
}

impl Segment {
    fn new(
        size: usize,
        start: usize,
        primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
        multiples: Rc<RefCell<Vec<usize>>>,
    ) -> Self {
        let (mut list, end_sqrt) = (
            vec![true; size],
            ((size + start) as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
        );
        primes
            .iter()
            .take_while(|&prime| *prime <= end_sqrt)
            .enumerate()
            .for_each(|(multiple_index, &prime)| {
                while multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] < start {
                    multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] += prime;
                }
                let skip = multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] - start;
                list.iter_mut()
                    .skip(skip)
                    .step_by(prime)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                        multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] += prime;
                    });
            });
        Self {
            list,
            index: 0,
            start,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Segment {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.start + self.index;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (
            0,
            Some(if !self.list.is_empty() {
                let end_index = self.list.len() - 1;
                if end_index >= self.index {
                    end_index - self.index
                } else {
                    0
                }
            } else {
                0
            }),
        )
    }
}

pub struct SegmentedCountedSieve {
    count: usize,
    size: usize,
    segment_size: usize,
    segment: Segment,
    segment_end_index: usize,
    primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    prime_index: usize,
    multiples: Rc<RefCell<Vec<usize>>>,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl SegmentedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize) -> Self {
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        let limit = (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        let primes: Rc<Vec<usize>> = Rc::new(SizedSieve::new(limit).collect());
        let start_index = if let Some(prime) = primes.last() {
            prime + 1
        } else {
            2
        };
        let segment_size = if size < CACHE_BYTES {
            size
        } else {
            CACHE_BYTES
        };
        let segment_end_index = start_index + segment_size;
        let multiples = Rc::new(RefCell::new(
            primes
                .iter()
                .map(|&prime| smallest_multiple_at_least(prime, max(prime.pow(2), start_index)))
                .collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
        ));
        Self {
            count: 0,
            size,
            segment_size,
            segment: Segment::new(
                segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&primes),
                Rc::clone(&multiples),
            ),
            segment_end_index,
            primes,
            prime_index: 0,
            multiples,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SegmentedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if self.prime_index < self.primes.len() {
            let prime = self.primes[self.prime_index];
            self.count += 1;
            self.prime_index += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        let start_index = self.segment_end_index;
        self.segment_end_index = start_index + self.segment_size;
        if self.segment_end_index < self.size {
            self.segment = Segment::new(
                self.segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                Rc::clone(&self.multiples),
            );
        } else {
            self.segment_end_index = self.size - 1;
            self.segment = Segment::new(
                self.segment_end_index - start_index,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                Rc::clone(&self.multiples),
            );
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for SegmentedCountedSieve {}

struct WheelFactorisedSegment {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
    wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
}

impl WheelFactorisedSegment {
    fn new(
        size: usize,
        start: usize,
        primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
        multiples: Rc<RefCell<Vec<usize>>>,
        wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
    ) -> Self {
        let (mut list, start_number, end) = (
            vec![true; size + wheel.seeds.len()],
            wheel.to_number(start),
            start + size,
        );
        let end_number = wheel.to_number(end);
        let end_number_sqrt = (end_number as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        primes
            .iter()
            .take_while(|&prime| *prime <= end_number_sqrt)
            .enumerate()
            .for_each(|(prime_index, &prime)| {
                for (totative_index, totative) in wheel.totatives.iter().enumerate() {
                    let multiple_index = totative_index + wheel.totatives.len() * prime_index;
                    if multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] > end_number {
                        break;
                    }
                    let addend = prime * totative;
                    while multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] < start_number {
                        multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] += addend;
                    }
                    while multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] <= end_number {
                        if let Some(index) = wheel.to_index(multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index])
                        {
                            list[index - start] = false;
                        }
                        multiples.borrow_mut()[multiple_index] += addend;
                    }
                }
            });
        Self {
            list,
            index: 0,
            start,
            end,
            wheel,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedSegment {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index + self.start <= self.end {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index + self.start);
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (
            0,
            Some(if !self.list.is_empty() {
                let end_index = self.list.len() - 1;
                if end_index >= self.index {
                    end_index - self.index
                } else {
                    0
                }
            } else {
                0
            }),
        )
    }
}

pub struct SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    count: usize,
    end_index: usize,
    segment_size: usize,
    segment: WheelFactorisedSegment,
    segment_end_index: usize,
    primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    prime_index: usize,
    multiples: Rc<RefCell<Vec<usize>>>,
    wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize, seed_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Rc::new(Wheel::new(seed_amount));
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count) as f64;
        let limit = (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        let primes = {
            let primes: Vec<usize> = WheelFactorisedSizedSieve::new(limit, seed_amount).collect();
            if primes.len() > seed_amount + 1 {
                Rc::new(primes)
            } else {
                Rc::clone(&wheel.seeds)
            }
        };
        let start_index = {
            let mut start_number = *primes.last().unwrap() + 1;
            while wheel
                .inverse_totative(start_number % wheel.modulus)
                .is_none()
            {
                start_number += 1;
            }
            wheel.to_index(start_number).unwrap()
        };
        let size_factored =
            (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).floor() as usize
                + seed_amount + 1;
        let segment_size = if size_factored < CACHE_BYTES {
            size_factored
        } else {
            CACHE_BYTES
        };
        let segment_end_index = start_index + segment_size;
        let multiples = Rc::new(RefCell::new(
            (0..primes.len() * wheel.totatives.len())
                .map(|index| {
                    let (prime_index, totative_index) =
                        (index / wheel.totatives.len(), index % wheel.totatives.len());
                    let prime = primes[prime_index];
                    smallest_multiple_at_least(
                        prime * wheel.totatives[totative_index],
                        max(prime.pow(2), wheel.to_number(start_index)),
                    )
                })
                .collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
        ));
        Self {
            count: 0,
            end_index: size_factored,
            segment_size,
            segment: WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&primes),
                Rc::clone(&multiples),
                Rc::clone(&wheel),
            ),
            segment_end_index,
            multiples,
            primes,
            prime_index: 0,
            wheel,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if self.prime_index < self.primes.len() {
            let prime = self.primes[self.prime_index];
            self.count += 1;
            self.prime_index += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        let start_index = self.segment_end_index + 1;
        self.segment_end_index = start_index + self.segment_size;
        if self.segment_end_index <= self.end_index {
            self.segment = WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                self.segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                Rc::clone(&self.multiples),
                Rc::clone(&self.wheel),
            );
        } else {
            self.segment_end_index = self.end_index;
            self.segment = WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                self.end_index - start_index,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                Rc::clone(&self.multiples),
                Rc::clone(&self.wheel),
            );
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {}
```

#### Remarks

Aside from that, I'd appreciate any other advice about diagnosing slow code or constructive feedback about improving code in general that you might be able to provide. Thanks.

P.S. This post was moved from Stack Overflow as it's apparently more suitable for this website instead. [The original post is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477863/why-is-this-implementation-of-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-so-slow).

Comment: Ok, I think one reason it (and the segmented variant) is slow is because if the overall list size is smaller than the "cache size", it does a check on whether it should use the cache size or the square root of the last number in the list for the size of the segments, making them smaller and more numerous than necessary, when it should probably just use the cache size instead. That said, that wouldn't explain why it's slower than the just segmented variant though (since that does the same thing, but isn't wheel factorised), so there's probably another more major reason for the slowdown.

Comment: As per my previous comment, I updated the code, benchmarking and profiling results (I think this is fine since there are no answers yet, right?). As expected, the performance of both `SegmentedCountedSieve` and `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` have improved, but the latter is still slower than all other variants, so this remains an open problem.

Comment: Try to heal this solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69791/sieve-of-eratosthenes-segmented-to-increase-speed-and-range/277754#277754

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved a part of the problem, which was that my previous implementations of the wheel factorised sieves didn't actually skip checking for multiples of the base primes used by their wheel. [After improving my implementation](https://nest.pijul.com/nicoty/sieve:main), I've been able to produce these benchmarking results (I changed the name of the primes used by the wheels from "Seeds" to "Bases"):

[image: Counted, Amount: 1000000, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Segmented Counted, Amount: 1000000, Sample Size: 100]

[image: Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Sample Size: 100]

And this was the terminal's output:

```
$ ./run.sh benchmark
   Compiling sieve v0.1.0 (/home/a/documents/projects/sieve)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 15.36s
     Running `target/release/examples/criterion --bench`
WARNING: HTML report generation will become a non-default optional feature in Criterion.rs 0.4.0.
This feature is being moved to cargo-criterion (https://github.com/bheisler/cargo-criterion) and will be optional in a future version of Criterion.rs. To silence this warning, either switch to cargo-criterion or enable the 'html_reports' feature in your Cargo.toml.

Gnuplot not found, using plotters backend
Benchmarking Sieves/Counted/Amount = 1000000: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 1965.1s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Counted/Amount = 1000000
                        time:   [376.16 ms 376.37 ms 376.70 ms]
Found 7 outliers among 100 measurements (7.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low severe
  6 (6.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Segmented Counted/Amount = 1000000: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 708.3s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Segmented Counted/Amount = 1000000
                        time:   [140.39 ms 140.47 ms 140.64 ms]
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  6 (6.00%) low severe
  1 (1.00%) low mild
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Bases = 3: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 825.6s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Bases = 3
                        time:   [162.25 ms 162.44 ms 162.70 ms]
Found 18 outliers among 100 measurements (18.00%)
  2 (2.00%) low severe
  8 (8.00%) low mild
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  7 (7.00%) high severe
Benchmarking Sieves/Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Bases = 3: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 827.0s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 10.
Sieves/Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted/Amount = 1000000, Bases = 3
                        time:   [163.40 ms 163.46 ms 163.58 ms]
Found 5 outliers among 100 measurements (5.00%)
  1 (1.00%) low mild
  4 (4.00%) high severe
```

Here's a flame graph produced from profiling the new implementation of the segmented wheel factorised counted sieve:

[image: Segmented Wheel Factorised Counted, Amount: 1000000, Seeds: 3, Duration: 60 seconds]

Here's a condensed version of the code of the new version:

```rust
use std::{
    cmp::{max, min},
    mem::swap,
    rc::Rc,
};

const CACHE_BYTES: usize = 8_000;

fn prime_count_overestimate(a: usize) -> usize {
    let ln_a = (a as f64).ln();
    ((a as f64 / ln_a) * (1.0 + 1.2762 / ln_a)).ceil() as usize
}

fn prime_count_underestimate(a: usize) -> usize {
    let f_a = a as f64;
    (f_a / f_a.ln()).floor() as usize
}

fn inverse_prime_count(a: usize) -> usize {
    let f_a = a as f64;
    let ln_a = f_a.ln();
    (f_a * (ln_a + ln_a.ln() - 1.0 + 1.8 * ln_a.ln() / ln_a)).ceil() as usize + 16
}

pub struct SizedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
}

impl SizedSieve {
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            list: vec![true; size],
            index: 2,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SizedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.list
                    .iter_mut()
                    .skip(self.index.pow(2))
                    .step_by(self.index)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                    });
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        if !self.list.is_empty() {
            let (underestimate, overestimate) = (
                prime_count_underestimate(self.list.len() - 1),
                prime_count_overestimate(self.list.len() - 1),
            );
            match (underestimate < self.count, overestimate < self.count) {
                (false, false) => (underestimate - self.count, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
                (false, true) => (underestimate - self.count, None),
                (true, false) => (0, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
                _ => (0, None),
            }
        } else {
            (0, None)
        }
    }
}

pub struct CountedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl CountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize) -> Self {
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        Self {
            list: vec![true; size],
            index: 2,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        while self.index <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.list
                    .iter_mut()
                    .skip(self.index.pow(2))
                    .step_by(self.index)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                    });
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.index;
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for CountedSieve {}

fn gcd(mut u: usize, mut v: usize) -> usize {
    if u == 0 {
        return v;
    } else if v == 0 {
        return u;
    }

    let k = {
        let i = u.trailing_zeros();
        let j = v.trailing_zeros();
        u >>= i;
        v >>= j;
        min(i, j)
    };

    loop {
        debug_assert!(u % 2 == 1, "u = {} is even", u);
        debug_assert!(v % 2 == 1, "v = {} is even", v);

        if u > v {
            swap(&mut u, &mut v);
        }
        v -= u;

        if v == 0 {
            return u << k;
        }

        v >>= v.trailing_zeros();
    }
}

struct Totatives {
    number: usize,
    current: usize,
}

impl Totatives {
    fn new(number: usize) -> Self {
        Self { number, current: 1 }
    }

    fn is_coprime(&self, number: usize) -> bool {
        gcd(self.number, number).eq(&1)
    }
}

impl Iterator for Totatives {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.current < self.number {
            if self.is_coprime(self.current) {
                let current = self.current;
                self.current += 1;
                return Some(current);
            }
            self.current += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (0, Some(self.number - self.current))
    }
}

struct Wheel {
    bases: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    modulus: usize,
    totatives: Vec<usize>,
    inverse_totatives: Vec<Option<usize>>,
}

impl Wheel {
    fn new(amount: usize) -> Self {
        let bases: Vec<usize> = CountedSieve::new(amount).collect();
        let modulus = bases.iter().product();
        let totatives: Vec<usize> = Totatives::new(modulus).collect();
        let inverse_totatives = {
            let mut out: Vec<Option<usize>> = vec![None; *totatives.last().unwrap() + 1];
            totatives.iter().enumerate().for_each(|(index, &number)| {
                out[number] = Some(index);
            });
            out
        };
        Self {
            bases: Rc::new(bases),
            modulus,
            inverse_totatives,
            totatives,
        }
    }

    fn inverse_totative(&self, index: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        *self.inverse_totatives.get(index)?
    }

    fn to_number(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
        self.modulus * (index / self.totatives.len()) + self.totatives[index % self.totatives.len()]
    }

    fn to_index(&self, number: usize) -> Option<usize> {
        Some(
            self.inverse_totative(number % self.modulus)?
                + self.totatives.len() * (number / self.modulus),
        )
    }
}

pub struct WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    wheel: Wheel,
    base_index: usize,
    non_factorised_size: usize,
}

impl WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    pub fn new(size: usize, base_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Wheel::new(base_amount);
        Self {
            list: vec![
                true;
                (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).ceil()
                    as usize + base_amount
                    + 1
            ],
            index: 1,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            base_index: 0,
            non_factorised_size: size,
            wheel,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedSizedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.base_index < self.wheel.bases.len() {
            let prime = self.wheel.bases[self.base_index];
            if prime < self.non_factorised_size {
                self.count += 1;
                self.base_index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            return None;
        }
        while self.wheel.to_number(self.index) <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                if prime > *self.wheel.bases.last().unwrap() && prime < self.non_factorised_size {
                    self.count += 1;
                    for factor_index in self.index..usize::MAX {
                        let multiple = prime * self.wheel.to_number(factor_index);
                        if multiple < self.non_factorised_size {
                            self.list[self.wheel.to_index(multiple).unwrap()] = false;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    self.index += 1;
                    return Some(prime);
                }
                return None;
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                if prime < self.non_factorised_size {
                    self.count += 1;
                    self.index += 1;
                    return Some(prime);
                }
                return None;
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let (underestimate, overestimate) = (
            prime_count_underestimate(self.non_factorised_size),
            prime_count_overestimate(self.non_factorised_size),
        );
        match (underestimate < self.count, overestimate < self.count) {
            (false, false) => (underestimate - self.count, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
            (false, true) => (underestimate - self.count, None),
            (true, false) => (0, Some(overestimate - self.count)),
            _ => (0, None),
        }
    }
}

pub struct WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    limit: usize,
    count: usize,
    wheel: Wheel,
    base_index: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize, base_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Wheel::new(base_amount);
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        Self {
            list: vec![
                true;
                (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).floor()
                    as usize + base_amount
                    + 1
            ],
            index: 1,
            limit: (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
            count: 0,
            wheel,
            base_index: 0,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if self.base_index < self.wheel.bases.len() {
            let prime = self.wheel.bases[self.base_index];
            self.count += 1;
            self.base_index += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        while self.wheel.to_number(self.index) <= self.limit {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                self.count += 1;
                if prime > *self.wheel.bases.last().unwrap() {
                    for factor_index in self.index..usize::MAX {
                        if let Some(multiple_index) = self
                            .wheel
                            .to_index(prime * self.wheel.to_number(factor_index))
                        {
                            if multiple_index < self.list.len() {
                                self.list[multiple_index] = false;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index);
                self.count += 1;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for WheelFactorisedCountedSieve {}

fn smallest_multiple_at_least(factor: usize, minimum: usize) -> usize {
    let remainder = (minimum + factor) % factor;
    if remainder != 0 {
        minimum + factor - remainder
    } else {
        minimum
    }
}

struct Segment {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    start: usize,
}

impl Segment {
    fn new(size: usize, start: usize, primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>, segment_index: usize) -> Self {
        let (mut list, end_sqrt) = (
            vec![true; size],
            ((size + start) as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize,
        );
        primes
            .iter()
            .take_while(|&&prime| prime <= end_sqrt)
            .for_each(|&prime| {
                list.iter_mut()
                    .skip(
                        max(
                            smallest_multiple_at_least(prime, size * segment_index),
                            prime.pow(2),
                        ) - start,
                    )
                    .step_by(prime)
                    .for_each(|multiple| {
                        *multiple = false;
                    });
            });
        Self {
            list,
            index: 0,
            start,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Segment {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index < self.list.len() {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.start + self.index;
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (
            0,
            Some(if !self.list.is_empty() {
                let end_index = self.list.len() - 1;
                if end_index >= self.index {
                    end_index - self.index
                } else {
                    0
                }
            } else {
                0
            }),
        )
    }
}

pub struct SegmentedCountedSieve {
    count: usize,
    size: usize,
    segment_size: usize,
    segment: Segment,
    primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    segment_index: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl SegmentedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize) -> Self {
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count);
        let limit = (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        let primes: Rc<Vec<usize>> = Rc::new(SizedSieve::new(limit).collect());
        let segment_size = if size < CACHE_BYTES {
            size
        } else {
            CACHE_BYTES
        };
        let segment_index = 0;
        Self {
            count: 0,
            size,
            segment_size,
            segment: Segment::new(segment_size - 2, 2, Rc::clone(&primes), segment_index),
            primes,
            segment_index,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SegmentedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        self.segment_index += 1;
        let start_index = self.segment_size * self.segment_index;
        if start_index + self.segment_size < self.size {
            self.segment = Segment::new(
                self.segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                self.segment_index,
            );
        } else {
            self.segment = Segment::new(
                (self.size - 1) - start_index,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                self.segment_index,
            );
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for SegmentedCountedSieve {}

struct WheelFactorisedSegment {
    list: Vec<bool>,
    index: usize,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
    wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
}

fn smallest_multiple_at_least_and_indivisible_by(
    factor: usize,
    minimum: usize,
    not_factors: &[usize],
) -> usize {
    debug_assert!(not_factors
        .iter()
        .all(|&not_factor| factor % not_factor != 0));
    let mut out = smallest_multiple_at_least(factor, minimum);
    while not_factors.iter().any(|&not_factor| out % not_factor == 0) {
        out += factor;
    }
    out
}

impl WheelFactorisedSegment {
    fn new(
        size: usize,
        start: usize,
        primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
        segment_index: usize,
        wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
    ) -> Self {
        let (mut list, start_number, end) = (
            vec![true; size + wheel.bases.len()],
            wheel.to_number(start),
            start + size,
        );
        if segment_index == 0 {
            list[0] = false;
        }
        let end_number = wheel.to_number(end);
        let end_number_sqrt = (end_number as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        primes
            .iter()
            .take_while(|&&prime| prime <= end_number_sqrt)
            .for_each(|&prime| {
                for factor_index in wheel
                    .to_index({
                        let multiple = smallest_multiple_at_least_and_indivisible_by(
                            prime,
                            start_number,
                            &wheel.bases,
                        );
                        if multiple != prime {
                            multiple / prime
                        } else {
                            multiple
                        }
                    })
                    .unwrap()..usize::MAX
                {
                    let multiple = wheel.to_number(factor_index) * prime;
                    if multiple <= end_number {
                        list[wheel.to_index(multiple).unwrap() - start] = false;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        Self {
            list,
            index: 0,
            start,
            end,
            wheel,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for WheelFactorisedSegment {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while self.index + self.start <= self.end {
            if self.list[self.index] {
                let prime = self.wheel.to_number(self.index + self.start);
                self.index += 1;
                return Some(prime);
            }
            self.index += 1;
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (
            0,
            Some(if !self.list.is_empty() {
                let end_index = self.list.len() - 1;
                if end_index >= self.index {
                    end_index - self.index
                } else {
                    0
                }
            } else {
                0
            }),
        )
    }
}

pub struct SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    count: usize,
    end_index: usize,
    segment_size: usize,
    segment: WheelFactorisedSegment,
    primes: Rc<Vec<usize>>,
    segment_index: usize,
    wheel: Rc<Wheel>,
    base_index: usize,
    max_count: usize,
}

impl SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    pub fn new(max_count: usize, base_amount: usize) -> Self {
        let wheel = Rc::new(Wheel::new(base_amount));
        let size = inverse_prime_count(max_count) as f64;
        let limit = (size as f64).sqrt().floor() as usize;
        let primes = Rc::new(
            WheelFactorisedSizedSieve::new(limit, base_amount)
                .skip(base_amount + 1)
                .collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
        );
        let size_factored =
            (size as f64 * wheel.totatives.len() as f64 / wheel.modulus as f64).floor() as usize
                + base_amount + 1;
        let segment_size = if size_factored < CACHE_BYTES {
            size_factored
        } else {
            CACHE_BYTES
        };
        let segment_index = 0;
        Self {
            count: 0,
            end_index: size_factored,
            segment_size,
            segment: WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                segment_size,
                0,
                Rc::clone(&primes),
                segment_index,
                Rc::clone(&wheel),
            ),
            primes,
            segment_index,
            wheel,
            base_index: 0,
            max_count,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > self.max_count {
            return None;
        }
        if self.base_index < self.wheel.bases.len() {
            let prime = self.wheel.bases[self.base_index];
            self.count += 1;
            self.base_index += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        self.segment_index += 1;
        let start_index = self.segment_size * self.segment_index + self.segment_index;
        if start_index + self.segment_size <= self.end_index {
            self.segment = WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                self.segment_size,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                self.segment_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.wheel),
            );
        } else {
            self.segment = WheelFactorisedSegment::new(
                self.end_index - start_index,
                start_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.primes),
                self.segment_index,
                Rc::clone(&self.wheel),
            );
        }
        if let Some(prime) = self.segment.next() {
            self.count += 1;
            return Some(prime);
        }
        None
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        let size = 1 + self.max_count - self.count;
        (size, Some(size))
    }
}

impl ExactSizeIterator for SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve {}
```

The new version of `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` is now faster than the least optimised `CountedSieve` and the flame graph shows that there's a reduction in the fraction of time spent on calls to `WheelFactorisedSegment::new`. That said, the problem is not yet totally solved as `SegmentedWheelFactorisedCountedSieve` is still a little slower relative to the the other counted sieves `WheelFactorisedCountedSieve` and `SegmentedCountedSieve`.

I suspect this slowdown could be due to the larger non constant-time index calculations done for each prime at the start of each segment (whereas I think these calculations are constant-time for `SegmentedCountedSieve` which might why it's faster even though it doesn't use a wheel), and I'd be grateful to anyone could provide suggestions on how I can improve that part of the implementation. In any case, I'd also appreciate any other programming-related improvements/advice I might be given. Thanks.